# Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."RSSample.war".POST_MODULE:

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, jboss

I want to deploy a jersey restful webservice that produces JSON.. but i get the following error

> 14:08:26,743 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-9) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."RSSample.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."RSSample.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "RSSample.war"
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
>   Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.  org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig
>       at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scan(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:209)
>       at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:105)
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>       ... 5 more

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
    see implementation details >http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html --> <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
>xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee >http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet->class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
           <param-value>com.ph.restful.sample.RSSample</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    </servlet>    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>    </servlet-mapping> </web-app>
```

My pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ph.restful.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>RSSample</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>RSSample</name>

<build>
    <finalName>RSSample</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.22.2</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

MyResource.java

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces("application/json")
public Product getIt() {

    Product prod = new Product();
    prod.setName("PS4");
    prod.setId("123");
    prod.setDescription("console game");
    return prod;
}
```

Product.java

```
private String name;
private String id;
private String description;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

[This is the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkJdv.png)

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
 <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
  <deployment>
     <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
    </exclude-subsystems>      
     <exclusions>  
      <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" />  
    </exclusions>  
  <deployment>
  </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here the problem is with multiple rest service implementations i.e., one is jboss rest implementation and another one is jersey.So here in this case , you may have to exclude the jaxrs of jboss by creating jboss-deployment-structure.xml file and excluding that.

Example of jboss-deployment-structure.xml 

    <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
        <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
        <deployment>
            <dependencies>
                <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
                <module name="org.hibernate"/>

            </dependencies>
            <exclude-subsystems>
                <subsystem name="jaxrs" />

            </exclude-subsystems>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- <module name="org.jboss.as.jsf"/> -->
                <module name="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
                <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider"/>
                <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations"/>
                <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind"/>
                <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core"/>

            </exclusions>
        </deployment>
    </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: where can i add the file on the jboss? what path? sorry beginner here :)

Comment: and what dependencies do i need?

Comment: If your application has RSSampleEAR project, put this file in RSSampleEAR/META-INF or if it is ju.st war put the file in WEB-INF folder.you need to exclude the jaxrs as shown above.You can use the same xml and it works fine.If any issues, comment here.

Comment: hi, thanks.. I edited my post and included my project structure screenshot.. its a .WAR file that i want to deploy.. can you provide the exact value that i can write on my jboss-deployment-structure.xml? i also included mt jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: Hi,Can you comment the line in your local jboss environment like below and try @wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\javax\ws\rs\api\main\module.xml comment the line <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" services="export"/> and no need to put the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file if we disable at module level.

Comment: it solved the problem by using wildfly... is there any way to do that to with jboss 7.1.1?